# Phase plane analysis when eigenvalue 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

I have two steady states, and I am trying to show the existence of heteroclinic orbits between them.

At one of the equilibria, if I have a zero eigenvalue, then could you tell me how to interpret this situation(eigenvalue=0)?

I am also curious whether I am still able to find the orbits, or whether it also depends on dimensions of the phase plane.

Thanks!

Comment: Though there is a [basic set of advices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382060/trajectories-that-connect-equilibrium-points/1382284#1382284), which can help you, nothing particular can be said or done without knowing your system...