# What is a trapping region?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

This is probably a relatively straight-forward question but I haven't been to source for a simple enough to understand illustration of a trapping region and bounded trapping region.

Definition:

> A trapping region of any dynamic system is a region such that every trajectory that begins in the trapping region will eventually remain in the region's interior for all forward time $t\geq 0$. [Trapping region Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapping_region)

Would someone kindly provide an easy to understand illustration?

Comment: Your question should provide definitions for "trapping region" and "bounded trapping region".

Comment: If you are into phase space illustrations of concept, take a look at picture [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382060/trajectories-that-connect-equilibrium-points/1382284#1382284). Just remove two equilibria at the border and put vectors that point to the inside of the domain instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having seen the definition, a bounded trapping region is probably just a trapping region which is bounded. As for a simple illustration, take the system of a ball rolling on uneven ground. The ball will obviously tend to roll downhill. If there is a hole or a ditch, or anything else vaguely bowl-shaped in the ground, and the ball starts within, then it will never roll out of that hole, which makes the hole a trapping region.

Answer (score 0):

A concrete example is given by Hénon in his famous paper [A two-dimensional mapping with strange attractor](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103900150). The quadrilateral $Q=ABCD$ is mapped to the curvilinear quadrilateral $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ which is totally contained in $Q$. Therefore, all orbits of the [Hénon map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map) starting in $Q$ remain in $Q$. Hénon gives explicit coordinates for the points $A,B,C,D$.

[image]

(Picture from the book "Chaotic evolution and strange attractors" by Ruelle)