# Prove existence of a Heteroclinic Orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, hamilton-equations

How would you go around proving that there exists a heteroclinic orbit between two equilibria ( in the problem I'm trying to solve, one is a stable node(say n) and the other is a saddle (say s))?

I started by finding the stable manifold of the stable node and the unstable manifold of the saddle point.

Next, I want to show that their intersection is not empty and so there must be a trajectory that starts at s and end at n. And therefore, a heteroclinic orbit.
But the problem is that the stable manifold only "covers" a neighborhood of n. Same for the unstable manifold.

So how do we figure out the neighborhoods I guess?
Or is there a better way to do this than using the stable and unstable manifolds?

Edit: This is the system of ODEs I'm dealing with.
 $$U' = V\\
 V' = -\frac{c}{D}V -\frac{\mu}{D} U (1-U)\\$$
All of the parameters are positive. and $c>\sqrt{4\mu D}$.
So we have two equilibria:
A stable node: (U,V) = (0,0).
And a saddle point: (U,V) = (1,0).

Thanks

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1382284/87697) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2462959/87697). Would be easier to say if you write your particular system.

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny. I'll take a look at those links.
Also, I added the system to the question!

Comment: Your system is quite similar to the one that was discussed in my second answer. I guess most of this solution applies to your problem.